# jQuery $.address() plugin: hashbang links colliding with HTML5 state support

Tags: jquery, html, history, jquery-address

Here's a scenario that describes the problem:

User A has a browser *with* HTML5 state support, and sends this link to User B:

`http://domain.tld/node`

User B, who uses a browser *without* HTML 5 state support, navigates to another node, and sends the link back to User A:

`http://domain.tld/node#!/another-node`

But when User A clicks the link, the content for `/node` is shown instead of `/another-node`.

Querying [Asual's jQuery `$.address()` plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) shows that it is interpreting the "hashbang address" as the hash value:

```
> $.address.value()
  "/node#/another-node"
> $.address.path()
  "/node"
> $.address.hash()
  "/another-node"
```

(Curiously the "!" is dropped from the hashbang.)

Can this ambiguity be overcome with a change in my implementation?

I could disable support for the history API if a hashbang is found in the URI, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by changing my implementation a bit.

Basically, I determine what the address *should* be based on the browser's capabilities, check that against what the address actually is, and if it doesn't match, use `location.replace()` to replace the address without creating a new history entry.

```
var addressValue = $.address.value(),
    initPath = window.location.pathname.replace(stateBasePath, ""),
    newLocation = baseUrl +stateBasePath + (supports_history_api() ? "" : "/#!") + (addressValue != "/" ? addressValue : initPath + window.location.search);
if (newLocation != window.location.href) {
    window.location.replace(newLocation);
}
```

This code should be executed as soon as possible – outside of a DOM ready function.

- `stateBasePath` is equivalent to the value you would use for `$.address.state()` (just an empty string if the site is located at the document root)
- `baseUrl` is the URI protocol and domain, e.g. `http://domain.tld` (no trailing slash)
- `supports_history_api()` is a little ditty taken from [Mark Pilgrim](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html)